# Writing socket server for existing socket client

Tags: c#, sockets, serversocket

I am new to Socket programming. We have to write socket server for existing c# socket client. Protocol is TCP, no TLS. The server code is not available.
How to ensure that server socket component will respond to Client call?
What are the important things that I need to be aware of?
Someone from the team was saying that I need to implement the same protocol that existing server was using. what does that mean?

Comment: I should note: writing a decent socket server from scratch is *seriously hard*, and a badly written socket server is often trivial to DOS; I strongly advise against it. I have a 3.5-part series [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) that builds up to using "Kestrel" and "Pipelines" to implement a socket server in C#, focusing on the framing/processing side, leaving Kestrel to worry about the raw sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets are just a mechanism to exchange bytes; exchanging bytes is relatively easy - but what you need to know is *what bytes to send* (and when receiving: what those bytes mean). This is the wire protocol.

The first thing you need to figure out is the raw transport details: is this TCP? UDP? what port number? is there TLS involved? etc. UDP is a packet protocol, TCP is a stream protocol, but in either case you need to find out how *messages* are represented on that protocol. If this is a well-known protocol, there may be a specification you can read - or even better: a prebuilt implementation. But essentially you're looking for details like [this (RFC6455, web-sockets)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) or [this (RESP===redis)](https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec/). The first thing this will usually define is the *framing* - for example in UDP, it could be as simple as "1 packet===1 frame, maxiumum SOME_NUMBER bytes", but in TCP it is more likely to be something like "frames are prefixed by a header of 14 bytes; the 3rd-7th bytes of that header denote the payload length as a little-endian 32-bit integer; the header is followed by the PAYLOAD_LENGTH bytes" - or similar. For a text-focused protocol, it could be "frames termination is 2 end-of-line sequences, accepting (some specified combination/permutation of CR/LF). Note further that the message's  protocol might not include the *data serialization* protocol; it *might* be as simple as "payloads are UTF-8 encoded text", but it *might* be "payloads are protobuf messages following SomeUnknown.proto", or something entirely bespoke and undocumented. It may even not be defined strictly (for example, gRPC usually *assumes* that it is talking protobuf, but that is not strictly required). Other common formats might be JSON or XML, but raw sockets are often more binary than text.

Comment: Protocol is TCP, no TLS. "frames are prefixed by a header of 14 bytes; the 3rd-7th bytes of that header denote the payload length as a little-endian 32-bit integer; the header is followed by the PAYLOAD_LENGTH bytes"--do we need to configure it in code?

Comment: Can I implement the Server socket in gRPC ?

Comment: TLS is mandatory for gRPC. And in fact it should be mandatory always. TCP without TLS is only useful when learning stuff.

Comment: @Annie configure? no; *implement* - every last bit - but first you need to find the "what"; as for gRPC: no, gRPC is an advanced protocol on top of HTTP2/HTTP3 - you don't want to worry about that here

Comment: @freakish "TLS is mandatory for gRPC" no, it isn't; it is *recommended*, but not mandatory - the Google and Microsoft transports both permit non-TLS usage; more generally, a *lot* of socket servers don't use TLS - it all comes down to what your usage is

Comment: @MarcGravell ok, fair enough, maybe it is not mandatory. Either way it should be used. And yes, lots of servers are insecure. Which is not an argument at all.

Comment: Its for on-premises only.. thats why they might not have implemented TLS

Comment: As long as the communication goes outside a machine it doesn't matter whether it is on-premise or not. And if it is used only locally, then why use TCP to begin with?

Comment: @freakish I don't entirely disagree (well, maybe a little), but the more important thing is to *match the protocol expectations*; if the existing clients do not use TLS, and the outgoing server does not use TLS: the replacement server cannot use TLS. Sure, adding a second port with TLS would be a nice addition, but that doesn't sound like the goal *in this question*

Comment: @MarcGravell you know, its like saying: hey, I don't know how to use keys, please build me a house without doors. I mean, sure, it is a requirement/expectation. Ridiculous, but hey, if the client pays...

Comment: yes you are right @freakish

Comment: What are the important things that I need to be aware of while implementing Socket Server for TCP? will it be similar to client socket-i mean TCP frames

Comment: @Annie everything; writing a *good* socket server is *freakishly hard* - you need to worry about: the memory model (for the buffers, payloads, etc), the threading/activation model, frame parsing, dead socket detection, keepalives, security, buffer overrun/underun protection, timeouts, DOS/DDOS, socket reuse, ephemeral port exhaustion, etc etc... as I say: if it were me, I'd delegate almost everything to Kestrel, and just worry about frame parsing!

Comment: @Annie btw, the Kestrel type for this is [`ConnectionHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.connections.connectionhandler); I haven't updated it to recent code styles, but here's a "redis-like" server that listens to RESP traffic on 6379 (the standard non-TLS redis port), and HTTP on 5000: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/toys/KestrelRedisServer/Program.cs; the real code is the async per-client loop in StackExchange.Redis.Server/RespServer.cs, `RunClientAsync`, L247